# Data attributes with CSS not so useful?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Am I missing something?  This MDN example looked quite useful at first glance:

```
article[data-columns='3'] {
  width: 400px;
}
article[data-columns='4'] {
  width: 600px;
}
```

But this is little different to using

`article[myAttr='3']{...`, or `article.cols3{...`

either of which can be manipulated fairly easily with javascript/jQuery.

What would be very powerful is:

```
article[data-fieldwidth]{
 width: data-fieldwidth;
}
```

but this isn't described anywhere and doesn't work in any of my tests.
Is that correct?

Comment: this `width: data-fieldwidth;` does't work (in `css`)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the value of an attribute you should use the CSS [`attr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) function. Currently the value of the property is not valuated and it's set as it is.

```
article[data-fieldwidth] {
 width: attr(data-fieldwidth);
}
```

But note that:

> The `attr()` function can be used with any CSS property, but support for properties other than `content`(property) is experimental.

Comment: yikes, currently no browser support other than content, nice catch

Comment: @BenSewards Unfortunately. I'm sure implementing this feature in browsers can be very tricky.